# How to implement Angular material design date-picker with start and end date

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, material-design, angular-material

My requirement is a date-picker it accepts start and end date.

[image]

On clicking of this, it will show date-picker and accept start and end date.

Can anyone suggest me how to implement this requirement.

Comment: Everything is clearly given on the main site itself. have you seen [Getting Started](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started)

Comment: [http://plnkr.co/edit/2ePb5nf8vH71iH5byP7q?p=preview] will help you.

Comment: I am sorry. you are looking for a date range picker.